# Access localhost from another computer

Tags: apache, web, virtualhost

I have created virtual host example.local in ubuntu.
I want to open it from another computer on the network. How can I do that?
I can open websites in /var/www/html using my ip: `http://11.22.33.4/example`
But how can I open http://example.local from another computer?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? Or by configuration. For latter: http://superuser.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Create a DNS route to your server ...

In your hosts file:

```
11.22.33.4    example.local
```

You find your hosts file here:

Windows: %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Linux / MAC: /etc/hosts

Comment: You could add the DNS route to your DNS Server, too, that way you would be able to access example.local from every computer on your network